# Getting env: node: input/output error running npm -v , after successfully installing node

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed node successfully using brew install node . Verified that node -v return version (v12.16.1) installed but when I tried to run npm -v it shows error
**env: node: input/output error**
Has anyone encountered this issue . I search all over but couldn't find right answer . has anyone solved this issue ?
My environment is MAC OS Catalina, V 10.15.3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same phenomenon as you on ubuntu. My problem seems to be an environment variable problem. Node uses an incorrect path. If I delete the environment variable, you can use the correct Node. You can use`strace` to find error reason.
`strace npm -v`
In my pc will find below error:

```
execve("/home/frank/.local/bin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/npm", "-v"], 0x7ffe4393df50 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/mnt/e/westz/zephyr-sdk-0.11.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/node", ["node", "/usr/bin/npm", "-v"], 0x7ffe4393df50 /* 25 vars */) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

So I know using error node path cause fail